# A Server Error Occurred on current command, Results, if any should be discarded

Tags: sql-server

I got this issue in different case, could any one please help out to fix this issue,

Current we have a Database(s) in Azure Environment and the Database is in SQL Server Managed instance,

we have Production and Non Production environment, our goal is to create a DDL Trigger in Production Database, and when ever an event happened we need to track those changes and on the fly we want to move those changes into non production environment,
for this I have Created a Database level Trigger in Production environment and inside the trigger Placed a INSERT statement with Four Part Name {DestinationServer.Database.SchemaName.TableName}

When i Create/Alter the Objects getting the Error "A Server Error Occurred on current command, Results, if any should be discarded"

so could you please let me know what went wrong/I missed,

I tried inserting a row into the Destination server and table, outside the Trigger it is working as expected, but it is failing only when we have INSERT/UPDATE statement(With Four part Name) in TRIGGER

Trigger Code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER TR_DatabaseLog ON DataBase
FOR CREATE_TABLE     ,ALTER_TABLE    ,DROP_TABLE
   ,CREATE_PROCEDURE ,ALTER_PROCEDURE,DROP_PROCEDURE
   ,CREATE_FUNCTION  ,ALTER_FUNCTION ,DROP_FUNCTION
   ,CREATE_TRIGGER   ,ALTER_TRIGGER  ,DROP_TRIGGER
   ,CREATE_VIEW      ,ALTER_VIEW     ,DROP_VIEW
   ,CREATE_TYPE                      ,DROP_TYPE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pEventData XML
           ,@pSchemaName         VARCHAR(100)
           ,@pObjectName         VARCHAR(100)
           ,@pObjectType         VARCHAR(50)
           ,@pEventType          VARCHAR(20)
           ,@pDataBaseName       VARCHAR(25)
           ,@pScriptVersion      INT
           ,@pApplicationVersion VARCHAR(10)
           ,@pEventText          XML
           ,@pCommandScript      NVARCHAR(MAX)
           ,@pHostName           VARCHAR(10)
           ,@pIPAddress          VARCHAR(100)
           ,@pChangedBy          VARCHAR(100)
           ,@pChangedDate        DATETIME
    SET @pEventData = EVENTDATA()
SET @pSchemaName         = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','VARCHAR(100)')  
SET @pObjectName         = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','VARCHAR(100)')  
SET @pObjectType         = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','VARCHAR(50)')  
SET @pEventType          = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','VARCHAR(20)')  
SET @pDataBaseName       = DB_NAME()

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[DataBaseLog]WHERE  SchemaName = @pSchemaName AND ObjectName = @pObjectName AND ObjectType = @pObjectType AND DataBaseName = @pDataBaseName)
BEGIN
    SET @pScriptVersion =0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @pScriptVersion= MAX(ScriptVersion) FROM [dbo].[DataBaseLog] WHERE  SchemaName = @pSchemaName AND ObjectName = @pObjectName AND ObjectType = @pObjectType AND DataBaseName = @pDataBaseName
END
SET @pScriptVersion =@pScriptVersion+1
SET @pApplicationVersion = CASE WHEN @pDataBaseName = 'ProductionDB' THEN 'V2_Prod' WHEN @pDataBaseName = 'StageDB' THEN 'V2_Stage' ELSE '' END

SET @pEventText          = @pEventData
SET @pCommandScript      = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
SET @pHostName           = HOST_NAME()
SET @pIPAddress          = CONVERT(VARCHAR(48),CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address'))
SET @pChangedBy          = SUSER_SNAME()
SET @pChangedDate        = GETDATE()

DECLARE @pEventText_Text NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
SET @pEventText_Text = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@pEventText)
        
INSERT INTO [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[DataBaseLog](SchemaName,ObjectName,ObjectType,EventType,DataBaseName,ScriptVersion,ApplicationVersion,EventText,CommandScript,HostName,IPAddress,ChangedBy,ChangedDate)
VALUES(@pSchemaName,@pObjectName,@pObjectType,@pEventType,@pDataBaseName,@pScriptVersion,@pApplicationVersion,@pEventText_Text,@pCommandScript,@pHostName,@pIPAddress,@pChangedBy,@pChangedDate)

END
```

Comment: That usually indicates an error with severity above 20, which is a fatal error and closes the connection. Are you getting any other error message? Please add your trigger code to your question

Comment: Do you have any related messages in the SQL Server error log? What is the security context configuration for the linked server?

Comment: Hello Charlie, i have added my Trigger code, pls go through it, and i am not getting any other message except the above i mentioned.

Comment: You're doing untested changes in the production database, and want them replicated to dev?????

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on `select @@version`

Comment: I can't see anything in the trigger that could cause this. There are some things to note: `SchemaName` `ObjectName` and `DB_NAME` should all be `nvarchar(128)`. The trigger code could be simplified a lot by doing a lot (or even all) of it in one query

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
 Jun 24 2021 23:23:51 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Hi Dan Guzman, i have verified Error Log, i don't find any Relevant error message

Comment: Hello HardCode, Not actually Replicate them from PROD, instead of Maintaining Object versioning in the same PROD Database, we thought to move to Non Prod Environment using Linked server, so